# Change html response to json response in rails during cross platform response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have created cross platform form to submit data. It sends data in json format, but rails controller response it as html. So that I always get error as.

```
    Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}

    test.html?batch[status]=0:88

    Navigated to file:///home/shital/workspace/shitalluitel.github.io/test.html?batch%5Bstatus%5D=0
```

Here is my rails log after my form submit...

```
    Started POST "/batches" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-13 08:55:59 +0545
    Processing by BatchesController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"batch"=>{"name"=>"eight", "course_id"=>"9", "start_date"=>"2016-12-12", "end_date"=>"2016-12-14", "status"=>"1"}}
      User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      Course Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE

 "courses"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "batches" ("name", "course_id", "start_date", "end_date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "eight"], ["course_id", 9], ["start_date", Mon, 12 Dec 2016], ["end_date", Wed, 14 Dec 2016], ["created_at", 2017-01-13 03:10:59 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-01-13 03:10:59 UTC]]
   (133.8ms)  COMMIT
 entered to true part 
Completed 200 OK in 147ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 135.6ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
render json: {your_response: "value"}, status: 200
```

or if you want nothing then

```
 render :nothing => true
```

You can change the status base on you needs.

Comment: what does your_response and value refer here

Comment: It will be your data. you put your data in there if  there's any. like for exam the result of the query you pud it in the value.

Comment: what kind of data? If want to send data of batch model then what should i do? I also want to check status?

Comment: you can do like `render json: {batches: @batches}` or` render json: @batches` you can remove status if you want. status is just for the html respose if it is a success or not

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in the controller response will automatically varies according to your platform

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render 'filename.html'}
  format.json { render json: @batches }
end
```

Comment: respond_to can be used in any action depending upon the requirement. For your case it's in create block